# Importing Android Project can't click finish

Tags: android

I am trying to move a project from one computer to another and having issues.  I have tried.

File > New > Project ... > Android Project from Existing code
and
File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace.

Both look like they get me to the same place.  I browse to the project location check the option to copy in existing workspace.  When a click finish nothing happens.  The dialog stays open and the project is to imported or opened.

Ryan

Comment: Check if you have something in Problems (Window -> Show View -> Problems) or Error Log

Comment: what os are you using

Comment: chk there is no error with project.properties

Answer (score 0):

**Simple export method I tend to follow:**

1. Save everything
2. Close Eclipse (And wait to completely close)
3. Then goto *workspace* folder
4. Select the project you're working on
5. Either simply copy to new location or compress to zip
6. Then using new system, either file open project by folder or zip

**To open compressed project or copied folder:**

1. File ---> Import
2. General ---> Existing Projects into Workspace
3. Browse either *root directory* or *archive file*

Screenshots below:

[image]

Comment: Where do you have the option to open project by folder or zip.  I should have said I am using Eclipse.

Comment: Follow tutorial image

Comment: This is one of the options I have tried.  After clicking browse and selecting the folder the Finish button is enabled but clicking on it does nothing.  I do not have any other projects in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is already a project in your workspace with same name. Check your workspace and rename that project.